# How to send HTML data with inline CSS and jQuery in a PHP request?

Tags: php, ajax, xmlhttprequest, httprequest

I am working on a project, I am creating a new HTML page on server by sending HTML with inline CSS as parameters with request variables.

The problem is that it's not writing the content if it encounter with a symbol like`#` a operator like `&&` or `&` or HTML symbols code like `&nbsp; &lt; &gt;`.

---

Code is given below:

### page.htm:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <script>
            function creathtmldoc()
            {
                var data = document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML;
                var xmlhttp;
                if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
                {
                    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                }
                else
                {
                    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                }
                xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function()
                {
                    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200)
                    {
                        alert("copy created");
                        alret(xmlhttp.responseText);
                        document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
                    }
                }
                xmlhttp.open("POST", "./creatpage.php?data="+data, true);
                xmlhttp.send();


            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="display">
            <div id="mydiv" style="border:2px solid #dddddd;margin: 0 auto;padding:70px;width:660px;height:900px;">
                <div style="clear:both;">
                    <div style="float:left;">Hello <strong>Gaurav</strong></div>
                    <div style="float:right;"><strong>&lt;@Your name&gt;</strong></div>
                </div>
                <div style="clear:both;">
                    <div style="float:left;">We are : <span style="font-family:courier new,courier,monospace"><em><strong>&lt;@Company name&gt;</strong></em></span></div>
                    <div style="float:right;"><em><strong><span style="font-family:courier new,courier,monospace">&lt;@Your designation&gt;</span></strong></em></div>
                </div>
                <div style="clear:both;">
                    <div style="float:left;"><span style="font-family:courier new,courier,monospace"><em><strong>&lt;@Company name with full address of company&gt;</strong></em></span></div>
                    <div style="float:right;"><span style="font-family:courier new,courier,monospace"><em><strong>&lt;@Your contact&gt;</strong></em></span></div>
                </div>
                <div style="clear:both;">&nbsp;</div>
                <div style="clear:both;">
                    <hr />
                    <div>We call you to inform about : <span style="font-family:courier new,courier,monospace"><em><strong>&lt;@Subject&gt;</strong></em></span></div>
                    <hr /></div>
                <br />
                Dear:<br />
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;We call you to inform about :<span style="font-family:courier new,courier,monospace"><em><strong>&lt;@Your message should be here !&gt;</strong></em></span><br />
                &nbsp;
                <hr />
                <div style="float:right;">Your sincerely<br />
                    <span style="font-family:courier new,courier,monospace"><em><strong>&lt;@Your name&gt;</strong></em></span></div>
            </div>
            <input type="button" onclick="creathtmldoc()" value="creat a copy of this html page >>"/>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

### creatpage.php

```
    <?php
$myfile = fopen("newpage.html", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
fwrite($myfile, $_REQUEST["data"]) or die("Unable write!");
fclose($myfile);
echo $_REQUEST["data"];
 ?>
```

By this demo, I wanna show that problem: this code not doing the thing which I want; it is not creating copy of the page. How to solve it?

How to send HTML data with inline CSS and jQuery in a PHP request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried **encodeURIComponent()** javascript function?